# Android - Ionic Input dispatching timed out

Tags: android, performance, ionic-framework, ionic3

> Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago. waitqueue length = 3, head.seq = 1993751, Wait queue head age: 6192.6ms.)
>
> com.app.**MainAcitivity**

I got this ANR Report from some users of my app who uses *Android 9*. In Main Activity cause some lag on entering the app on some devices. i also got some messages about HeapTaskDaemon, Threads

[image: mainactivity]

i use Ionic v3, cordova v9

Comment: How did you fix this?